# indexes, indexes, indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an enormous table (in Oracle 12c) which of course needs indexes. 
This table is also updated very often so if what I've learned is correct then the less indexes I have on this table the better performance will be when it comes to DML operations on said table.

Of course I want to have the correct number of indexes so that the queries against it don't suffer.

I put together this little example for myself as a kind of guide to creating indexes. Does this look accurate?

```
CREATE INDEX FOO ON FOO.BAR ("COL1", "COL2", "COL3"); -- COL1 should be the column which is most frequently queried

SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE COL1 = 'FOO'; -- uses index FOO

SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE COL1 = 'FOO' AND COL2 = 'BAR'; -- uses index FOO

SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE COL1 = 'FOO' AND COL2 = 'BAR' AND COL3 = 'BAZ' -- uses index FOO
```

So there would be no need for a single index on col1 or on col2 .. if col3 is queried by itself

(where col3 = 'blah')

I would need an index on col3.

if col2 and col3 were queried together

(where col2 = 'blah' and col3 = 'blahblah')

then I would need an index on col2, col3 ... but if I had a query where col2 and col3 were used together than I wouldn't need a single index on either col.
How does this all sound?

Comment: "Enormous table" is a term which means different things to different people.  Tell us how many rows, how many columns, your OS, how much memory is allocated, what performance issues you have noted, is this a new table or an existing table, a production database or a test?

Comment: I have a 200GB table with 200GB of indexes which is updated ~170 times per second... context is everything and you should do what you need.

Comment: the table is 5 GiB in size and will grow ... it has 24 columns ... I realize things are generally peculiar to a case by case basis but I was just looking for some general insight. OS is SuSE, 4 GiB of memory. Test database so there will be more resources come production ...

Comment: how about an a composite index, e.g. on col1,col2,col3 ?

Comment: @Thomas - that's what the question shows?

Comment: This is too big an area for general insights really, but [start with the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/data_acc.htm#PFGRF94772).

Comment: @Alex Poole  then i dont get it... if u create a composite index in oracle and you are querying only one of the 3 cols, then the composite index will be used (if the CBO decided in that way)

Comment: What is the cardinality of these columns? Maybe consider Bitmap Indexes (one for each column). What meas "is updated very often"? Is it only one single session doing the updates or many different users? In case of many users the Bitmap Indexes are not suitable! Note, Oracle is also able to combine several B*Tree Indexes (i.e. you have three indexes, one for each column)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. A 'normal' btree composite index is generally only useful to speed up queries if you include the leading column(s) of the index in the where clause.

So if you have an index on c1, c2 and c3 and you issue a query that only filters on c2, the index is probably not useful. I say probably because there are scenarios where Oracle can make use of that index. One is where it can do a skip scan (but I have not had much luck with performance when using something like that). Another is if you have really wide rows in the table making the table large, but columns c1, c2 and c3 are small values, then the size of the index might be much less than the size of the table and Oracle can use the index (via a fast full scan) to answer the query.

If you often need to query with just c1 or just c2 or just c3, you probably need 3 indexes. As always it depends on your data and requirements what makes most sense.